# django REST API calls scripts from different python environment

Tags: python, django, conda

I have a django rest API which would allow to call different prediction method. These methods/scripts are in different conda environment. I can certainly work with one enviroment script, by activating the enviroment of that script and run django service in it. But I am not sure how to do it for another script.
My last resort would be to run two django services in different enviroment settings, but looking for a better approach.

I think, i would like to activate the enviornment(depending on the method being called) programitically in the django

Comment: Is it impossible to move the scripts into the same environment as the Django app? The point of having separate environments is so they don't conflict with one another, so trying to do that is generally not a good idea.

Comment: I tried, but they cant be in same enviorment because of the conflict in required packages

Comment: so, I was thinking, may be I can call the environments in python script itself, like using subprocess. But so far no luck.

Comment: I used subprocess to call scripts from different envirornments. So it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used subprocess to call scripts from different envirornments, where i used the python interpreter from the environment of the given script.

```
subprocess.run(['../anaconda3/envs/allennlp/bin/python','../predict.py', '-s', serialization_dir, '-c', params, '-i', input_file_path, '-o', output_file_path])
```